# Display ggplotly chart without toolbar

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to hide the plotly toolbar when displaying a reactive ggplot chart within a Shiny app. Currently my code looks like this:

```
renderPlotly( ggplot(users_activated(), aes(x = month, y = n)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity"))
```

I have tried `config(displayModeBar = F)` to no avail.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to have `ggplotly`? You need to add `%>% ggplotly()` to render a ggplot as a plotly object. Then you can add `%>% config(displayModeBar = F)`. As it stands, your question lacks the information needed for debugging.

Comment: The current code displays a plotly object of the ggplot, I am trying to remove the plotly toolbar from that object.

Comment: Using `ggplot(users_activated(), aes(x = month, y = n)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") %>% ggplotly() %>% config(displayModeBar = F)` inside `renderPlotly` does not work

Comment: wrap `ggplot` inside `ggplotly`. See below;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your `ggplot` object to a `plotly` object before you can render it as one, or use `plotly` functions on it. `ggplotly` does that. Below, is an example using `mpg` dataset.

```
ggplotly(ggplot(mpg, aes(class, displ, color = manufacturer)) +
  geom_point()
  ) %>% 
  config(displayModeBar = F)
```

[image]